# How to set a blank input form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I want to create a form where a user is able to update his/her email and password.

```
<%= form_for @customer do |c| %>
    <%= c.label :email%>
    <%= c.text_field :email%>
    <%= c.label :email_confirmation %>
    <%= c.text_field :email_confirmation%>
    <%= c.label :password%>
    <%= c.password_field :password%>
    <%= c.label :password_confirmation%>
    <%= c.password_field :password_confirmation%>
    <%= c.submit("Edit profile")%>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that I don't want them to be filled in when just looking at it.
So it should have something like:

```
Email [blank]
Email confirmation [blank]
Password [blank]
Password confirmation [blank]
```

So how do I have this to be blank in stead of pre-filled in by Rails?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an empty value:

```
<%= c.text_field :email, :value => "" %>
```